# How to check the locations using LatLng values?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I'm a beginner in android and my question is regarding about google map api v2.I drew a path using my current position and my destination and I got some  locations of a bus which is travelling through my path. How can I check the buse's location LatLng values are matching with my path LatLng values???

Comment: Your question does not strike a chord, Basically it is very unclear, please be very precise

Comment: Do you want to check it programmatically or just want to display it on the map?

Comment: @apurva i want to display it on the map. but i don't know the mechanism to check it and display. please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Location crntLocation=new Location("crntlocation");
crntLocation.setLatitude(currentLatitude);
crntLocation.setLongitude(currentLongitude);

Location newLocation=new Location("newlocation");
newLocation.setLatitude(server_latitude);
newLocation.setLongitude(server_longitude);


float distance = crntLocation.distanceTo(newLocation);  in meters
//distance =crntLocation.distanceTo(newLocation) / 1000; // in km
if(distance<200){
    //You are within 200 meter range
}
```

Put this in a loop.